# How do you create interesting background and ambiance for your fictional work?

Tags: plot, subplot

A background is a very critical aspect of your fiction story/novel and can easily make or break it.

For instance, Dan Brown's famous novel, *Da Vinci Code* was all about the backgrounds. The mysterious properties of the number *phi* (which are actually mysterious), the interesting historical events surrounding the Knights Templar, Roman Emperor Constantine, Jesus Christ, Mary Magdalene, etc. was what made the novel ultimately famous and extraordinarily popular. The actual plots and events surrounding Robert Langdon were just circumstantial and a result of the usual plotting process that could be typical of almost any other novel.

Another example where the background and ambiance shines is Harry Potter - A magical school for prodigal children with extraordinary gifts and a whole new world surrounding that! Though, Rowling had to invent a lot of things from scratch as opposed to Brown, who just modified the actual historical facts a bit to make them more interesting to the readers.

In any case, how do you come up with such backgrounds for your novel? If you were to write a novel (be it historical or pure sci-fi), what all do you research and how do you shape that research into backgrounds and ambiance that should be an interesting/fascinating read for your readers?

Comment: This is a question of great intrinsic interest, but I have voted to close because it is too broad for the Stack Exchange format. I agree that a good background can hugely add to the appeal of a story, but for that very reason the question of how to make a background interesting is almost as broad as how to make a story interesting. If you haven't already, you might like to browse the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange.   More narrowly defined questions about researching different types of background (historical, science fiction etc.) would fit here on Writers SE.

Comment: On a different note, much as I love the Harry Potter books, I don't think that J K Rowling's worldbuilding was particularly original. It certainly wasn't consistent. She made a rather sketchy and derivative background come alive through her great plots and characters. And Dan Brown is so famous for just making stuff up that he has a whole *TV   Tropes* page named after him: ["Dan Browned"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DanBrowned). For all that, he certainly does have the knack of picking a setting that appeals to readers.

Answer (score 3):

What Dan Brown did was [read a lot](https://www.google.com/search?q=dan%20brown%20read%20a%20lot). He is famous for the amount of research he does for each of his novels, and all that knowledge is not lost after the writing but keeps on accumulating. Dan Brown simply knows so much about what he wants to write about, that he can write about it with the same intimate familiarity you could write about your living room. **To create a rich, vibrant, and convincing background, immerse yourself in what makes up that background.**

## Do research.

Answer (score 2):

> In any case, how do you come up with such backgrounds for your novel? If you were to write a novel (be it historical or pure sci-fi), what all do you research and how do you shape that research into backgrounds and ambiance that should be an interesting/fascinating read for your readers?

How do you come up with your ideas is entirely up to you. I write fantasy, set in made-up medieval secondary world, but I do research real history of the similar time period and geography, pick out what interests me and what I consider cool and unusual, deconstruct and re-use it.

The settings and backstory should work for your narrative. No matter how fascinating your world (whether it is real or imagined) is, if you don't have a compelling story, set over that backdrop, you have nothing to write about.

Everyone has their own way of doing research, and there is no single right way to do so. The Internet makes research much faster—one just have to check your sources.

There is a wrong way, however, which is NOT to do research at all...